# how to avoid OutOfMemoryError when saving json to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory, sharedpreferences

i need to save an objects array to `SharedPreferences` , at first the code was saving array "as is" with `Serializable` objects .

i have tried to save object as json to avoid this problem but this is still happening . even my Try and Catch block didn't help me to at least not crash the application .

1 . is saving to json to `SharedPreferences` is lighter the save file with `Serializable` object ?

2 . what is the best way to save array with objects ?

3 . how to avoid `OutOfMemoryError` crashes ? and detect them ?

this my my code for saving :

```
editor.putString(key, new Gson().toJson(object));
```

Comment: You must have a really large object

Comment: I would advice you using another way of persisting your data to disc than sharedprefernces. Sharedprefernces are ideal for saving simple key-value objects and not so much for complex data structures. I feel an sqlite implementation by using an ORM will be more appropriate for this use case.

Comment: agree with @Tobrun or just save the serialized string into a file

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you using another way of persisting your data to disc than sharedprefernces. Sharedprefernces are ideal for saving simple key-value objects and not so much for complex data structures. I feel an sqlite implementation by using an ORM  will be more appropriate for this use case.

Comment: i agree ! i was received this project few days ago and i trying to understand how to handle this before we will make the structure change as i agree we should .